# Anyone know where I can get documentation on the SQLI protocol?

Tags: informix

I've been searching for good documentation on the SQLI wire protocol, but my google-fu isn't up to the task. I've searching on IBM's site with no success.

Answer (score 1):

SQLI is a proprietary protocol used by Informix for client server communication. Being proprietary, the details of the protocol by Intellectual Property laws and are not published.
Can you be more specific about WHY you are looking for this information and WHAT you are planning to do with that?